# Need to limit my Displayed results using REGEXP_REPLACE & SPLIT_PART

Tags: sql, regex, psql

So I am running the Query below and I need to consolidate my results if possible based on case

SO here is the query

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(note,'Comments:',2),'\s+$', '') AS reason,
  COUNT(*)
FROM notes
WHERE note LIKE 'Sending disabled due to reason%'
  AND note NOT LIKE '%ultiple%'
  AND note NOT LIKE '%www.%'
  AND REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(note,'Comments:',2),'\s+$', '') NOT LIKE '%http%'
  and created_at > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 days'
GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(note,'Comments:',2),'\s+$', '')
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Now I get lots of results I want.. but I have one set that's all basically the same "Spam" but within the database, there are a number of case differences

Spam(Real Estate)
 Spam (Real Estate)
 spam
 Spam
 Spam(Test)
 CV Spam
 Spam (Real estate)
and more

I really just want to have anything that has Spam in the note to count under one Spam title vs all the variations. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may add one AND.
**AND note ilike '%spam%'** . ilike is similar to LIKE, but its case insensitive.
Then you can customize the query to get the spam count